# C# Unity Inventory - List.FindAll() not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am super new to C#, so apologies if this is a simple question or has already been answered. I've been looking at other SO questions, trying the exact methods they use, and am still having no luck.

In Unity, I have an Inventory Object class that I can use to create Inventories in my game:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Inventory", menuName = "Inventory System/Inventory")]

public class InventoryObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<InventorySlot> Container = new List<InventorySlot>();

    public void AddItem(ItemObject newItem, int itemAmount)
    {
      bool inventoryHasItem = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < Container.Count; i++)
      {
        if (CurrentSlotHasItem(Container[i], newItem)) {

          if (Container.FindAll((InventorySlot currentSlot) => CurrentSlotHasItem(currentSlot, newItem)).Count < newItem.maxStackSize)
          {
            Container[i].AddAmount(itemAmount);
            inventoryHasItem = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if (!inventoryHasItem)
      {
        Container.Add(new InventorySlot(newItem, itemAmount));
      }
    }

    private bool CurrentSlotHasItem(InventorySlot currentSlot, ItemObject item)
    {
      return currentSlot.item == item;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot
{
  public ItemObject item;
  public int amount;

  public InventorySlot(ItemObject _item, int _amount)
  {
    item = _item;
    amount = _amount;
  }

  public void AddAmount(int value)
  {
    amount += value;
  }
}
```

This works great, except for this line:

```
Container.FindAll((InventorySlot currentSlot) => CurrentSlotHasItem(currentSlot, newItem)).Count < newItem.maxStackSize
```

For some reason, no matter what I use for the `findAll()` predicate, I always get the same amount in my inspector - `1`. Which means that `.Count` never goes above 1, and I can go way above my `ItemObject.maxStackSize`.

This is an example `ItemObject` class I have:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Food Object", menuName = "Inventory System/Items/Food")]

public class FoodObject : ItemObject
{
    public int healthAmount;

    private void Awake() {
        type = ItemType.Food;
        maxStackSize = 25;
    }
}
```

This is also my `Player` script that adds the items to the inventory. It just adds them based off of `OnTriggerEnter`.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InventoryObject inventory;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var item = other.GetComponent<Item>();

        if (item)
        {
            inventory.AddItem(item.item, 1);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }    
    }
}
```

Here's some screenshots of my Unity console/inspector, with these two lines added to my `InventoryObject` class. You can see that `.Count` never going above 1.

```
if (CurrentSlotHasItem(Container[i], newItem)) {

  Debug.Log(Container.FindAll((InventorySlot currentSlot) => CurrentSlotHasItem(currentSlot, newItem)).Count);
  Debug.Log(Container[i].amount);

// rest of class
```

[image: Ore Object Definition]
[image: Unity Console]
[image: Inventory Item]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you instantiating that “newItem”? In your “CurrentSlotHasItem” function, you’re comparing 2 objects by reference, are you sure they’re the same instance? Also, just doing Container.Count will be easier to read then the Container.FindAll, unless there’s another reason you’re doing it like that?

Comment: Hey Scott, I added my player script that actually calls `addItem`, hopefully that helps. That's also what I'm not sure of! Maybe that's why the items are never equal? I'm also doing `FindAll` instead of `Container.Count` because I need the count of this specific item in the inventory, not the count of the container.

Comment: You can still pass a lambda into your .Count function. I would simplify it for now to work through the problem, do a simple foreach and keep a counter, debug and check whether the counter is incrementing when you expect it to. If not, then there may be a problem elsewhere rather than the findall

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know that you could pass a function to .Count. I will try that! Hopefully here soon I'll be answering my own question. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what I was thinking here. All I needed to do to get `maxStackSize` to work was changing the logic inside of `AddItem`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Container.Count; i++)
{
        if (Container[i].item.id == newItem.id) {
          if (Container[i].amount < newItem.maxStackSize)
          {
            Container[i].AddAmount(itemAmount);
            inventoryHasItem = true;
            break;
          }
        }
}
```

It just compares `Container[i].amount` to `newItem.maxStackSize`. If it's under, it will stack the item. Otherwise, it creates a new item in the inventory.